# PyTorch, AttributeError: module 'shape' has no attribute ''

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I'm just trying to run the MNIST code on a GPU. The version for python in my conda environment is 3.8 and for PyTorch it's 1.8, so they are both pretty updated. The example_data is the MNIST dataset, and I was able to get torch.Size([1000, 1, 28, 28]) as the result for example_data.shape on Jupyter Lab.

So what could be the reason that I'm getting this error message? Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MNIST5.py", line 45, in <module>
    example_data.shape
AttributeError: 'torch.FloatTensor' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Here is the part of the code that caused the problem. I got it from a tutorial online, and it basically just downloaded the datasets and try to get the shape of it.

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/', train=True, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

examples = enumerate(test_loader)

batch_idx, (example_data, example_targets) = next(examples)
example_data.shape
```

Comment: What is the "MNIST code"?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to elaborate on that. MNIST is a dataset with 1000 handwritten digits for training a convolutional neural network that works as a classfier

Comment: I also realized that my title is wrong. It's 'size' has no attribute.

Comment: I'm asking about the actual code (`MNIST5.py`) not the MNIST dataset, can you show us the part that fails?

Comment: I just edited the post and you can see it now!

Comment: How have you defined `test_loader`? the data loader defined above is `train_loader`. With this correction, the error won't be raised.